# Kotlin - Deserializing json string with ktor

Tags: json, kotlin, deserialization, json-deserialization, ktor

I consume a service answering object which contains a string of a json object as follow

```
{
    "id":"13211",
    "json":"{\"id\": \"5489491\", \"title\": \"Biblioth\u00e8que de la Grognarde\", \"items\": [{\"label\": \"Label\", \"type\": \"TYPE_1\", \"data\": {\"value\": \"VALUE\"}}, {\"label\": \"Label\", \"type\": \"TYPE_2\", \"data\": {\"label\": \"LABEL\"}}]}"
}
```

I want to deserialize the json field to use a data class object instead of a string but cannot find a way to make it work.

I mapped my object and created a custom deserializer to handle that json and map it to a proper object.
Here are my data classes

```
@Serializable
data class WrapperResponse(val id: String, val json: Response)

@Serializable(WrapperDeserializer::class)
data class Response(
    val id: String,
    val title: String,
    val items: List<Item>,
)

@Serializable
data class Item(
    val label: String,
    val type: ItemType,
    val data: AbstractItem?
)

@Serializable
class AbstractItem()

@Serializable
data class Type1Item(val value: String): AbstractItem()

@Serializable
data class Type2Item(val label: String): AbstractItem()
```

And here is my deserializer

```
object WrapperDeserializer : KSerializer<Response> {
    override val descriptor: SerialDescriptor = buildClassSerialDescriptor("Item") {
        element<String>("id")
        element<String>("title")
    }

    override fun deserialize(decoder: Decoder): Response {
        decoder.decodeStructure(descriptor) {
            var id: String? = null
            var title: String? = null
            while (true) {
                when (val index = decodeElementIndex(descriptor)) {
                    0 -> id = decodeStringElement(descriptor, 0)
                    1 -> title = decodeStringElement(descriptor, 1)
                    CompositeDecoder.DECODE_DONE -> break
                    else -> error("Unexpected index: $index")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code does not work and raise an `JsonConvertException: Illegal input` exception with the message `Unexpected JSON token at offset X : Expected start of the object '{', but had ' ' instead` as if the space between different objects in a list was an error.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Why do you need a custom serializer for that JSON? What does the `val data: AbstractItem?` property correspond to?

Comment: I need a serializer because without a serializer I get an exception (the same that I got with the serializer). `val data: AbstractItem?` correspond to a polymorphic field which structure depend on the type field.

Comment: Do you have a dependency on kotlin-serialization (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-serialization) ?

Comment: No but since I use ktor I have a dependency on ktor-serialization-kotlinx-json

Answer (score 0):

The type of json in the provided json(which is to be deserialised) is string. But in data class `WrapperResponse`, the json is of type `Response`. Pass non-stringified json as bellow to remove the error

```
{"id":"13211","json":{"id":"5489491","title":"Bibliothu00e8que de la Grognarde","items":[{"label":"Label","type":"TYPE_1","data":{"value":"VALUE"}},{"label":"Label","type":"TYPE_2","data":{"label":"LABEL"}}]}}
```